# Upload video 360 to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm uploading a 360 video to Facebook but when I upload the video it looks flat.
I tried to upload the video via web and it works fine so the metadata shouldn't be the problem.
I use the API Graph with this code:

```
    //get video byte[], tested that it doesn't lose metadata uploading 360 photo
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), "r");
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    f.read(b);

    //set upload params
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putByteArray("video.mp4", b);
    params.putString("title", file.getName());

    //create and init request
    GraphRequest graphRequest =
        new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "me/videos",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                if(response.getRawResponse() == null){
                  Log.e("UploadServiceParentFB", "fail to upload");
                  showNotificationError(getResources().getString(R.string.no_permissions));
                }
                else {
                  file.delete();
                  showNotification();
                  Log.d("UploadServiceParentFB", "" + response.getRawResponse());
                }
              }
            });
    graphRequest.executeAndWait();
```

I tried with 2000x1000 and 1920x1080 video resolution.

Maybe I need to add any parameters to the request?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to use `executeAndWait` instead of `executeAsync`. Also please add file size as a param and then check, rest of the code looks fine so should be working.

`params.putInt("file_size", b.length);`